# How to change the header color in docfx standard template

Tags: docfx

Have been struggling with the header color in the css for some while. I was able to change the footer, but not sure how to access the header element and change the color. Please reference the screenshot for context
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add a directory structure like this to root:

```
templates/
  my-template/
    styles/
      main.css
```

In docfx.json, add `"templates/my-template"` in the `template` object inside the `build` object:

```
    "template": [
      "default",
      "templates/my-template"
    ]
```

In templates/my-template/styles/main.css, add something like:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: green;
}

.subnav {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

As reference, you can see the classes that construct the navbar this way:

- Run `docfx template export`.
- Find `_exported_templates/default/partials/navbar.tmpl.partial`.

To modify the partial directly, copy `navbar.tmpl.partial` here and modify:

```
templates/
  my-template/
    partials/
      navbar.tmpl.partial
```